# Vanishing of the first Chern class of a complex vector bundle

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Suppose that $E\to M$ is a $\mathbb{C}^n$-bundle with a metric. This is equivalent to saying that there exists a chart $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $M$ and $\phi_{\alpha,\beta} \colon U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\to  U(n)$ such that $\{\phi_{\alpha,\beta}\}$ satisfies a cocycle condition. (In this case, we say the structure group of $E$ is reduced to $U(n)$.)

Is the following true? If so, can you give a sketch of proof or give me a reference?

**Question:** The first Chern class $c_1(E)=0$ if and only if the structure group of $E$ can be reduced to $SU(n)$?

I know that if $L$ is a line bundle over $M$, then $c_1(L)=0$ if and only if $L$ is trivial. The above question seems to be a natural generalization.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Both conditions are equivalent to the condition that the top exterior power of $E$ is trivializable.

Comment: I have a question. Does the Chern class here is with integer coefficient or rational coefficient?

Comment: @haohaizi with integer coefficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting question! The 'if' part is true and I think the 'only if' part is also (but this would need verification).

Suppose that $E$ is a $SU(n)$-bundle. Given any $SU(n)$-connection form on $E$, its curvature form $\Omega$ is a basic $\mathfrak{su}(n)$-valued 2-form on the principal $SU(n)$-bundle associated to $E$. As such, it can also be understood as a $\mathfrak{su}(n)$-valued closed 2-form on $M$. According to Chern-Weil theory, the first Chern class is given by the cohomology class of $\frac{i}{2\pi} \mathrm{tr}\,\Omega$, which vanishes since the matrices in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ are traceless.

Suppose that $E$ is  $U(n)$-bundle with vanishing first Chern class. The structure group of $E$ can be reduced to $SU(n)$ if and only if there exists a $SU(n)$-principal subbundle in the $U(n)$-principal bundle $P$ associated to $E$, which is equivalent to the existence of an 'equivariant' function $f : P \to U(n)/SU(n)$ (with the canonical left $U(n)$-action on the quotient). In turn, this is equivalent to the existence of a section of the associated fiber bundle $P(U(n)/SU(n))$. Since $SU(n)$ is a normal subgroup of $U(n)$, we deduce that $Q = P(U(n)/SU(n))$ is a principal bundle, so it admits a section if and only if it is trivial. In fact, $U(n)/SU(n)$ being isomorphic to $U(1)$, it is a $U(1)$-principal bundle. Letting $U(1)$ act on $\mathbb{C}$ in the standard way, we can form the complex line bundle $F = Q(\mathbb{C})$. Thus, the reduction of the structure group of $E$ from $U(n)$ to $SU(n)$ is equivalent to the line bundle $F$ being trivial, that is, as you pointed out, equivalent to $F$ having a vanishing first Chern class.

I think, but I am not quite sure, that looking at how a connection form on $P$ induces a connection form on $Q$, we can infer that the vanishing of the first Chern class of $E$ implies the vanishing of the first Chern class of $F$. If true, the reduction to $SU(n)$ would be guaranteed.

Comment: Could you explain why the existence of $SU(n)$ subbundle equivalent to the existence of an equivariant function $f$?

Comment: @Dai This is a special case of a characterization of sections of an associated bundle to a principal bundle. In my explanations below, I reverse the logical order from that in my answer above. Given a $G$-principal bundle $P$ ($G$ acts freely on $P$ from the right) and a left $G$-space $F$, we construct the associated bundle $F(P) := P \times_G F$ i.e. the quotient of $P \times F$ by the left $G$-action $g \cdot (p,f) \mapsto (p \cdot g^{-1}, g \cdot f)$. There is a correspondence between sections of $F(P)$ and left-equivariant map $s : P \to F$ i.e. $s(p \cdot g^{-1}) = g \cdot s(p)$.

Comment: @Dai In our case, $G = U(n)$ and $F = U(n)/SU(n)$ with the usual left $G$-action. Set $H = SU(n)$. Given $s : P \to F$ as in the previous comment, set $P_H := s^{-1}([H])$ and observe that the free right $G$-action on $P$ restricts to a free right $H$-action on $P_H$. Hence the principal $H$-subbundle. Conversely, given a principal $H$-subbundle $P_H \subset P$ (this inclusion is $H$-equivariant), define $s : P \to F$ by $s(P_H) := [H] \in G/H$ and $s(q \cdot g^{-1}) := g \cdot s(q)$ for $q \in P_H$ and $g \in G$; Observe that $s$ is well-defined and that it is left-$G$-equivariant.

Comment: Thanks! These are great explanation!

Comment: I am still bothered by something. You mentioned there's a correspondence between sections of associated vector bundle $F(P)$ and left-equivariant map $s$. But I know a fact that every vector bundle admits smooth global sections. Would this naturally guarantee the existence of such $s$?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I take what I said back. F(P) is not a vector bundle...

Comment: @Dai If $f \in F$ is fixed by $G$, for any $G$-principal bundle $P$ over $M$, the map $s : P \to F : p \mapsto f$ is equivariant and corresponds to the (morally 'constant') global section $M \to F(P) : m \mapsto f$. For instance, if $F$ is a vector space and $G$ acts linearly, $f = 0$ is such a point: The zero section of a vector bundle is a global section. Similarly, if $G$ does nothing to $F$, $F(P) = M \times F$ has plenty of sections. However if $F = G/H$ and $G$ acts on $F$ in the usual way, no such $f$ exists so the existence of a global section is not guaranteed by this observation.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful.

Comment: If someone is able to finish the proof by relating the 1st Chern class of $E$ and $F$, please let us know. Thanks!