# the first chern class of complex vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $\xi^\mathbb{C}$ be an $n$-dimensional complex vector bundle over a manifold $M$, $n\geq 2$.

**Question 1:**
Are there any practical methods to detect whether the first Chern class (with integer coefficients, **NOT** with rational coefficients) 
$$c_1(\xi^\mathbb{C})$$ is zero or not?

I have found two ideas:

(I). The first idea is given in the [mathoverflow question as in the following picture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219951/the-first-chern-class-of-complex-vector-bundles).

**Question 2:** Where to find the **references** giving the formula
$$
c_1(\wedge ^n \xi^\mathbb{C})=c_1(\xi^\mathbb{C})?
$$

[image]

(II). The second idea is given in [Vanishing of the first Chern class of a complex vector bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332461/vanishing-of-the-first-chern-class-of-a-complex-vector-bundle).

**Question 3:** Any **references** giving whether the following is true or not?
"The first Chern class $c_1(\xi^\mathbb{C})=0$ if and only if the structure group of $\xi^\mathbb{C}$ can be reduced to $SU(n)$."

But I think the answer is about rational coefficient Chern class, not integer coefficient as we want.

Comment: No, that's not about rational coefficients, it's about integer coefficients. A proof, essentially, is given by calculating the cohomology rings of $BSU(n)$ and $BU(n)$, though one can do it more geometrically.

Comment: Question 2: $\wedge^n \xi$ is what you get when you replace the transition functions $\varphi$ of $\xi$ with $\det \varphi$. If you have a connection that's locally given by $A$ on $\xi$, then on $\det \xi$ it's locally given by $\text{tr }A$. Now apply the Chern-Weil definition of first chern class and fiddle a bit with matrices.

Comment: @MikeMiller Chern-Weil definition is about rational coefficient.

Comment: Fair enough. The first comment still holds.